# Azure bot service web app bot no resource found

Tags: botframework, http-status-code-404, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

Now nothing working or loading for my web app bot in azure portal. I tried to download the source code which was unsuccessful then tried to check all app service settings which wont even load and shows the error code 404. Have not found any solution that works yet and dont know what is causing this. Also when trying to open the configuration blade it doesnt load and reads 'failed to load settings'. I am not working or developing the bot locally, only working in Azure and with QnA maker. The bot is not responding at all. Has anyone had this issue before? Any help greatly appreciated!

[image: azure all app service settings not loading]

Comment: Are you still seeing this issue to list your resource from the Azure portal?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the resource group, then look in the `Activity Log`. Narrowing down the time frame might be your biggest issue, but you can also filter for resource type (`resource type == Bot Services`).